# Samsung Galaxy Player has music in folder, not playing

Tags: music, samsung-galaxy-player, media-files

I have a Samsung Galaxy Player that I have added music to from iTunes, into the "music" folder.   But the songs do not appear in the music player to be played, or placed in a play list?  Any ideas?

Comment: What format is this music? Are they MP3 files, or AAC or something else?

Comment: How have you added the files? IIRC, the media rescan process doesn't always kick off if you don't add the files in a way it expects.

Comment: Try rebooting or unmounting/remounting your SD card. Perhaps the music folder is also not where the application looks by default although intuition would say otherwise. Also, how did you add them from iTunes? A built in media transfer component or manually? If manually you may run into media protection problems.